# Boost.Log Custom Severity with Default Global Logger

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I'm trying to setup custom severity levels with Boost.Log v1.54 though I've been getting an issue which hasn't been mentioned in any of the Boost.Log stackoverflow entries so far.

The following is the code:

```
//Within ILogger abstract class header under public:
enum LogLevel
{
    kAll = 0,
    kDebug,
    kInfo,
    kWarning,
    kError,
    kFatal,
    kOff,
};


//Within Logger.cpp
#include "ILogger.h"

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT( _logger, sources::severity_logger_mt< ILogger::LogLevel > )
```

The following is the error:

```
Boost_1_54\boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp(252): error C2664: 'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::aux::severity_level<LevelT>::set_value' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level' to 'ILogger::LogLevel'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              LevelT=ILogger::LogLevel
1>          ]
1>          Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
1>          Boost_1_54\boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp(460) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::basic_severity_logger<BaseT,LevelT>::open_record_unlocked<ArgsT>(const ArgsT &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              BaseT=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::basic_logger<char,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<ILogger::LogLevel>,boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex>>,
1>              LevelT=ILogger::LogLevel,
1>              ArgsT=boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity,const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level>
1>          ]
1>          Logger.cpp(104) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::basic_composite_logger<CharT,FinalT,ThreadingModelT,FeaturesT>::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<Keyword,Arg>>(const ArgsT &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              CharT=char,
1>              FinalT=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt<ILogger::LogLevel>,
1>              ThreadingModelT=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex>,
1>              FeaturesT=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sources::severity<ILogger::LogLevel>>,
1>              Keyword=boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity,
1>              Arg=const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level,
1>              ArgsT=boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::keywords::tag::severity,const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::trivial::severity_level>
1>          ]
```

Comment: What happens if you replace those enums with `const int`s?  Does the code compile?

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to build I therefore stopped using the get global logger macro (BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT) and used a local severity_logger_mt, which accepted ILogger::LogLevel without an issue.